# How does confirm() work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, alert

I was thinking about how the native functions in JavaScript work today, and I can across `alert()` and I figured it must use `createElement()` or make an element and use `innerHTML`, but I can't figure out the complete code it would need to create a popup element, and make two buttons, then return `true` or `false` based on the one click.
jowes said:

> usually JS is async; why is alert special? how and why does it create UI elements in a different way from my own scripts?

Here's the code I have figured out:

```
function confirm(message) {
    message = message.replace(/"\n"/g, "<br />")
    createElement();
//The create Element is very complicated to create the text box including message. . .
//These two functions are tied to the button's onclick's.
    function clickOkay() {
        valueToReturn = true
        return true;
    }
    function clickCancel() {
        valueToReturn = true
        return false;
    }
    //here, the user hits the button, and sets valueToReturn
    return valueToReturn;
}
```

But I don't understand how it stops the background script, if accessable, or how createElement() works, (but thats a question for another time)

Comment: `confirm()` is a native function. It's not implemented with JavaScript.

Comment: `while (true) { /* but this will make the entire page unresponsive and your script will be prompted to be terminated */ }` - from an approach perspective, everything in Browser JavaScript wrt the UI must be based on callbacks such as to "not block the UI". Take a look at existing "modal dialogs" for how callbacks (and overlay HTML elements) are used.

Comment: I like the intuition that this question shows - usually JS is async; why is `alert` special? how and why does it create UI elements in a different way from my own scripts?

Comment: .. but `alert()` is not special from JavaScript's view. No further JS can occur until it returns.

Comment: I mean it's "special" in that it's synchronous. It behaves in a way that user scripts can't.

Comment: @joews `confirm()` is no different than any other synchronous input source; albeit one that is connected-to-keyboard.

Comment: @user2864740  yes, but that doesn't happen if I implemeneted a function using the script I have above, it wouldn't stop background or Interval script like `alert()`, `prompt()` and `confirm()` do

Comment: @wyatt And everything is explained at the boundary: synchronous is synchronous. The alert/confirm work because the UI processing for them is handled outside of JavaScript execution context. In implementations such modal dialogs may include a while-loop around the message dispatch (or a while-loop on a semaphore with the UI on a different thread). [There was actually a "fun issue" with older FF versions that would allows some asynchronous callbacks to occur while in an `alert`.]

Comment: @user2864740 I understand :) my point is that the fact that it's synchronous at all is interesting. From the OP's point of view it's interesting to think about why this is, and how one might try to emulate it with asynchronous user code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `confirm()`-function is a native function brought to you by every browser.
It is not created by using javascript. However if you want to reproduce that behaviour you go a way similar to this:

```js
function myConfirm(text, cb){
    
    // We need this later
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
     
    // First we create a div which holds the alert and give it a class to style it with css
    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
    overlay.className = 'myConfirm';
  
    // The box holds the content
    var box = document.createElement('div');
  
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  
    // We append the text to the div
    box.appendChild(p);
    
    // Create yes and no button
    var yesButton = document.createElement('button');
    var noButton = document.createElement('button');
    
    // Add text and events to the buttons    
    yesButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Yes'));
    yesButton.addEventListener('click', function(){ cb(true); body.removeChild(overlay); }, false);
    noButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode('No'));
    noButton.addEventListener('click', function(){ cb(false); body.removeChild(overlay); }, false);
    
    // Append the buttons to the box
    box.appendChild(yesButton);
    box.appendChild(noButton);

    // Append the box to the Overlay
    overlay.appendChild(box)
    
    // insert the Overlay with box into the dom    
    body.appendChild(overlay);
    
}

myConfirm('Hello there!', function(value){ console.log(value); });
```

```css
.myConfirm{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.myConfirm>div{
  width:200px;
  margin:10% auto;
  padding:10px 20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:#ccc;
}

.myConfirm div p{
  text-align:center;
}

.myConfirm div button{
  width:40%;
  margin:0 5%;
}
```

This could be an implementation for a self-made alert-box.
**Note** that the native alert is a `synchronous`-function. That means the browser stops the JavasScript-engine until the alert-box is closed. You cant clone that behavior but at least you can give the function a callback which is called, when one of the buttons is clicked. In this case the callback just logs the value to the console.

Hope I could help here!

**UPDATE** to the updated question
Back in the days when JavaScript was new `confirm` was a valid way to ask the user for a specific value. `confirm`, `prompt` and `alert` are special functions from these days which behave completely different than normal functions since they break the JavaScript-"flow".
When you ask why: Well - maybe it was a nice to have-feature back in these days. Note that in earlier versions `alert` looked like a system-message (in IE it still does). At least in Firefox you can nowadays interact normally with your browser even if alert is called.
That's why it is merely used for debugging only today (and even here `console.log` is the better choice).

I am pretty sure that today (in FF) the alert is rendered with browser-intern html and CSS, too.

Answer (score 8):

`alert`, `confirm`, and `prompt` are all DOM APIs that are implemented by the browser. They do not create DOM elements to represent them, and their functionality cannot be exactly recreated with JavaScript because you cannot force the JavaScript engine to wait for the user to click one of your buttons. You can only come close by requiring a callback that will contain the result of the dialog that you create.

```
function customConfirm(message, callback) {
    message = message.replace(/"\n"/g, "<br />")
    createElement();
    //The create Element is very complicated to create the text box including message. . .
    function clickOkay() {
        callback(true);
    }
    function clickCancel() {
        callback(false);
    }
}
customConfirm("Hello World!", function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Of course, you would have to tie the two click functions to the click events of the buttons.

Comment: Can you add an example of tying the two click functions to a button's click event?

Comment: @SamC I don't recall the context of that comment. Mind expanding a bit?